# How do I access the terminal without logging in to the desktop?

Tags: command-line

Using [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) to install Oracle Java I accidentally restarted on Step 10 and now I can't get past the login screen. I'm wondering if there is a way to access terminal without logging in and finish the last 4 steps? After I try to sign in it takes me right back to the sign in screen.

Answer (score 16):

To access a Terminal from the Login screen press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2 or 3 and so on F7 is the where the GUI is running)

From there you can contiune where you left off or try to re do it again.

You can also access one from the recovery mode, boot press shift when GRUB appears and enter recovery, then enter the root terminal.